# How can I offer different RSS-Feeds by category?

Tags: categories, rss

I want to write a WordPress-Blog about some quite different topics. I will write most of it in English, but some topics are only interesting for Germans. The posts in the German-category will be in german. 
I guess it's not interesting for most readers who read the English categories whats in the German category.

So I would like to have one RSS-Feed for all posts in the German-Category and one RSS-Feed for all other posts. How can I realise this?

Per default are two Feeds available:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyBlog RSS Feed" href="http://localhost/wordpress/feed/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="MyBlog Atom Feed" href="http://localhost/wordpress/feed/atom/" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that WordPress (or any plugin I've installed) makes this by default. Just go into your category and take a look at the feeds.